# compiling GWT module on IntelliJ

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 10.5 on Windows 7. How do you change the output style of GWT generated JS code (obfuscated, detailed, pretty)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open File | Project Structure, find your module, select 'GWT' node under it and change 'JavaScript output style'.